# How to do a GROUP BY and COUNT within json_build_object() in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, common-table-expression

I want to perform multiple `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` operations on a table(or CTE) and have the output as a singe JSON.

Consider the following table in a Postgres database:

| Name | Author | Publisher | Language |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Book1 | Jason | Penguin | English |
| Book2 | Jason | Macmillan | English |
| Book3 | Paul | Macmillan | English |
| Book4 | Julia | Macmillan | English |
| Book5 | Julia | Penguin | English |

This is my current SQL query

```
WITH first_selection AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM books
    where language='English')
SELECT json_build_object('author_options', json_agg(DISTINCT(author)),
                         'publisher_options', json_agg(DISTINCT(publisher)))
FROM first_selection
```

For which I get this output:

```
{
    "author_options":["Jason","Paul","Julia"],
    "publisher_options":["Penguin,"Macmillan"]
}
```

The problem is I also need the count of books for each publisher but I keep getting an error saying that nested aggregations are not allowed.

I need the count of books in the JSON output. Not necessarily in any specific structure, but the information needs to be there. Basically I want an output that looks something like this:

```
{
    "author_options":["Jason","Paul","Julia"],
    "publisher_options":["Penguin,"Macmillan"],
    "publisher_details": {
                             "Penguin": 2,
                             "Macmillan": 3
                          }
}
```

How do I count the number of books per publisher and put the result into the JSON?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but: `distinct` is not a function. Enclosing the column following the keyword is useless.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah that makes sense. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate the publishers in a separate step and then include that into the final result:

```
with first_selection as (
  select *
  from books
  where language = 'English'
), pub_info as (
  select json_object_agg(publisher, cnt) as details
  from (
    select publisher, count(*) as cnt
    from first_selection
    group by publisher
  ) t
)
SELECT json_build_object('author_options', json_agg(distinct author),
                         'publisher_options', json_agg(distinct publisher),
                         'publisher_details', (select details from pub_info))
FROM first_selection
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=18996eb8a1dde4e146b829e6e3ab3476)

Comment: Suppose I have multiple columns for which I want the count(like with publisher). Do i need to create separate steps for each?
Say I have 50 other columns for which I want the count. Can they all be done in one step or do I need to write 50 steps like how you did with 'publisher'?

(I can modify my question to include this if required)

Comment: If you have 50 different ways to group, you will need 50 GROUP BY queries

Answer (score 2):

```
 create table books (Name varchar(50), Author varchar(50), Publisher varchar(50), Language varchar(50));
 
 insert into books values('Book1',  'Jason',    'Penguin',      'English');
 insert into books values('Book2',  'Jason',    'Macmillan',    'English');
 insert into books values('Book3',  'Paul',     'Macmillan',    'English');
 insert into books values('Book4',  'Julia',    'Macmillan',    'English');
 insert into books values('Book5',  'Julia',    'Penguin',      'English');
```

Query:

```
 WITH first_selection AS (
     SELECT *
     FROM books
     where language='English')
 , publisherscount as
 (
 select Publisher, count(*) pcount
 from books
 group by publisher
 )
 SELECT json_build_object('author_options', json_agg(DISTINCT author),
                          'publisher_options', json_agg(DISTINCT publisher),
                          'publisher_details',(select   array_to_json(array_agg(json_build_object(publisher,pcount)))
                          from publisherscount)
                         )
 FROM first_selection
```

Output:

| json_build_object |
| --- |
| {author_options : [Jason, Julia, Paul], publisher_options : [Macmillan, Penguin], publisher_details : [{Macmillan : 3},{Penguin : 2}]} |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8726ea52c902a3e96987c7c909a87b7c)*